# Updating NSDocument status without undo?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, appkit, nsdocument

I have a document-based application but I am not using undo. How do I change the status of my window to be 'dirty' and certain times?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NSDocument has an `-updateChangeCount:` method. The constants you can pass are described [in Apple's documentation](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000008-DontLinkElementID_4).